# Unable to get the collection names from MongoDB python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have `mongodb` running on azure portal. I can connect to it using `nosql booster`. I have created a DB `TestDb` and have added 3 collections to it. I am trying to connect to it using python as below:

```
mongo_url = 'mongodb://' + <username> + ':' + <password> + '@' + <url> + ':' + port + '/' + admin
client = MongoClient(mongo_url)
db = client.get_database('TestDb')
print(db)
print(db.list_collection_names()) # Error at this line
```

Below is the output of db:

```
Database(MongoClient(host=['<name>.documents.azure.com:10255'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'TestDb')
```

but  at `db.list_collection_names()` it shows error `<name>.documents.azure.com:10255: timed out`.

I have rechecked everything and all looks good to me. But not sure why not able to do above using python. Please help. Thanks

Comment: can you try `db = client['TestDb']` instead of `db = client.get_database('TestDb')`?

Comment: @po.pe Yes just tried and got the same error.

Comment: Can you access one of the collections directly with `db['collection_name']`?

Comment: @po.pe using `print(db['userdetails_collection'])` I got `Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['<name>.documents.azure.com:10255'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'TestDb'), 'userdetails_account')`. What does this mean.?

Comment: What version of pymongo are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth mentioning you are using Cosmos DB.

Although it's compatible with MongoDB on wire protocol level, it has own specifics.

Try to follow Quick Start snippets for Python from Azure Portal. It should have most accurate connection settings.

My best guess is it requires [ssl enabled oclientside](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/tls.html#basic-configuration):

```
mongo_url = 'mongodb://' + <username> + ':' + <password> + '@' + <url> + ':' + port + '/' + admin + '?ssl=true'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also using a test DB but nothing worked. This develop DB had some dummy configurations so the solution was adding a `tlsAllowInvalidCertificates` to my url:

```
url = f"mongodb://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}:{PORT}/{DB_NAME}?authSource=admin&ssl=true&tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=true"
```